# Handling multiple XML elements with the same XPath

Tags: xml, xpath, robotframework

I have problems modifying multiple elements with the same Xpath in the same XML. Here is the code:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    XML
Library    String

*** Variables ***
${XMLpath}   AbsolutePath.xml
${Xpath}    GM/BODY/CMss/message  #(there are two elements with this xpath)

*** Test Cases ***
TestCase
    ${root}  Parse Xml  ${XMLpath}
    @{CMmessage}     Get Elements Text   ${root}  ${Xpath}
    
    ${CMmessage1}  Set Variable  @{CMmessage}[1]
       #...CMmessage1 modifications...
    Set  ${root}  ${CMmessage1}  \  ${Xpath} #Here is failing due there are multiple elements (2) matching the XPath
    
    ${CMmessage2}  Set Variable  @{CMmessage}[2]
       #...CMmessage2 modfications...
    Set  ${root}  ${CMmessage1}  \  ${Xpath} #Here is failing due there are multiple elements (2) matching the XPath

    Save Xml  ${root}  ${XMLpath}
```

There is the problem, Xpath given is not unique. I have tried with index:

`Set  ${root}  ${CMmessage1}  \  ${Xpath}[1]`
`Set  ${root}  ${CMmessage1}  \  ${Xpath}[2]`

but this was useless... Does anyone have any idea how to handle with index in Robotframework-XMLlibrary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, finally I found the problem. Using

```
Set  ${root}  ${CMmessage1}  \  ${Xpath}[1]
```

is wrong

```
@{CMmes1}     Get Element Text   ${root}  ${Xpath}
@{CMmes2}     Get Element Text   ${root}  ${Xpath}
...
Set  ${root}  ${CMmes1}  \  GM/BODY/CMss[1]/message
Set  ${root}  ${CMmes2}  \  GM/BODY/CMss[2]/message
```

is fine. The point is that I have 2 CMmes, not 2 messages inside CMes.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do some processing on those elements.

Use the [Get Elements](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/XML.html#Get%20Elements) keyword.

Comment: Hello Helio, the Get Elements keyword will give me a list with all the elements that have the same path OK. But If I want to Set Text or Set any of the Attributes (e.g.  replacing the tag "message" for "message1" and "message2") It's not possible because Set Attribute uses the path, no the Element...

Comment: In principle, you can use the objects returned by `Get Elements` just like any other kind of locator. I am "expecting" the same behavior as in SeleniumLibrary, where this is possible. But there must be a way to distinct the elements. Otherwise, how could any API or program work on them?

Comment: IDK the behavior in SeleniumLibrary. Is this something like this "${elements}[0].Text" (using get elements instead get elements text)

Comment: Sorry, only experimenting I could tell.